# Layout constraint programmatically with id cannot be found for both UIView (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, layout, constraints

Hello dear stack overflow experts.
I'm stuck working with constraints and here is my case.
I have two `UIView`s, one of them is a child of another (let's call them a `parent` and a `child`).
For `parent` I define constraint the next way:

```
let constraint = child.widthAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: parent.widthAnchor,
            multiplier: 1)

constraint.identifier = "constraint-width"
constraint.isActive = true
```

But when I try to find this constraint applied for `parent` by id I failed.

```
let relatedConstraint = parent.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == "constaint-width" }.first
```

Could you please tell where I do it wrong?
I'm expecting the same constraint be applied for both `UIView`s.

My task is to update constraint using `parent` since it should be related to `child`' width using multiplier (in percent).

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your filter - you have "constaint" instead of "constraint".  If you know you need a reference to a constraint later it is easier to store that reference in a property rather than having to go look for it.  If you are going to use identifiers, use a static property to hold the string literal; that way you can avoid problems with using a different literal value by mistake

Comment: If you want a percentage width relationship between the two views, then specify the correct `multiplier` to start with.  You can't modify the `multiplier` of a constraint once it is created, only the `constant`.  You will need to remove the existing constraint and create a new one if you want to change the multiplier